# How do I get all values from an excel column and put them into an array in python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am creating a signup page for my app for a school project and I am using openpyxl to read an excel file and I do not know how to get all the data from one column into an array.

The file looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2YrO.png).

And i want the array to look like this if it was printed:

[example1, example2, example3]
so that i can then check through to see if someone already has that username signed up.

sidenote: I know excel is not secure to use as a login database but it is for a school project so security is not really needed.

Comment: Write a loop to get each cell in the column.

Comment: You should include whatever code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# The source xlsx file is named as source.xlsx
wb=load_workbook("source.xlsx")

ws = wb.active
second_column = ws['B']

# Create the list
usernames = [cell.value for cell in second_column[1:]]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I assumed the code-comments within would suffice. What kind of explanations would a snippet like this need?